# angular 7 does not ask if to use routing when i create a new project

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, command-line-interface, angular7

I was formerly using Angular version 6, now I have upgraded to 7. But when I try to create a new project in CLI using `ng new [app-name]` it just starts without asking if I want to include routing in my project or the styling.

P.S: I have the latest version of Angular i.e 7.0.2.

Comment: `ng new --help` explains that you need to use `ng new [name] --routing`.

Comment: Thanks, @trichetriche, but I really want it to work I do `ng new [name]`. I ran the `--routing` command and I got a bunch of error, `package install failed`

Comment: it works now, I had to uninstall everything, node and angular, cleaned my cache before that. Then I reinstalled all. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ng new {Project-name}` command by default creates project without routing.

You need to set routing flag as true while creating project as below(by default this routing flag will be false),

```
ng new {Project-name} --routing=true
```

[Go through angular documentation for more details](https://angular.io/cli/new)

Comment: When I go through the linked documentation, that documentation states

"Provides interactive prompts for optional configuration, such as adding routing support. All prompts can safely be allowed to default."

On Windows git-bash this is missing, on cmd it works

Answer (score 9):

`ng new --help` run this command this will open up the things you can do while creating project.

[image]

Lets say I wanna create Angular project with routing and .scss styles then I would do it by the following command.

```
ng new project-name --routing=true --style=scss
```

Comment: @DamilolaOluwafemi It's my please, please mark correct answer if your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but when I tried to initialize the project using git bash on windows it doesn't prompt the questions about routing and style sheets. However, when I tried to use the same command in the terminal inside de VS code it worked. It's strange since both terminals runs with bash.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

ng new projectname --routing --style=scss --directory=./

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

while creating project you should use this to enable routing:

```
ng new {Project-name} --routing=true
```

**To enable routing in our Angular application, we need to do three things:**

1. create a routing configuration that defines the possible states for our application.
2. import the routing configuration into our application.
3. add a router outlet to tell Angular Router where to place the activated components in the DOM.