# Choosing stylesheet and routing doesn't work on "ng new" on Git Bash - how to fix?

Tags: angular-cli, git-bash

I have the latest versions of angular-cli/npm/node, but when I type "ng new" it doesn't ask whether I want the routing or not (or which stylesheet).

I don't know if something's wrong with my Git Bash, these are my versions.

```
$ node -v
v12.5.0
$ npm -v
6.9.2
```

```
$ ng version
Angular CLI: 8.0.6
Node: 12.5.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...
Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------ 
@angular-devkit/architect    0.800.6
@angular-devkit/core         8.0.6
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.0.6 
@schematics/angular          8.0.6 
@schematics/update           0.800.6
rxjs                         6.4.0
--
```

The "ng new" command basically works - other than asking about styling and routing, I would love for some help :)

P.S. - the weird thing is: in VS-Code(using Bash) it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be [like in Angular 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53153265/6309) for [`ng new`](https://angular.io/cli/new):

> `ng new --help` explains that you need to use `ng new [name] --routing=true`

Same for `--style` (`=css|scss|sass|less|styl`)

By default, `routing` is set to `false`, and `style` to `css`.

Comment: I see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14938 redirects here!

Comment: They wrote that I should post it on StackOverflow :) 
So it can't ask me? I have to actively add this text? It's not that crucial lol it's just annoying.

Comment: Apparently, you need to add those options indeed.